# Project manager going around me to VP to change the way my team works

Tags: professionalism

I'm a tech manager.  I work with a project manager who...plays games...

Her recent game is that she's decided to go to the VPs of our company and complain about the way our team does QA.  She's calling meetings with the QA and the VP but excluding me.  I get the feeling that she's doing this on purpose to draw attention away from some of the shenanigans she engages in and possibly set up qa to be a fall guy for something.

How can I manage this situation or establish a boundary of "if you have a problem with our work product, come to me and we will discuss it.  Do not change the team dynamics or procedures of the team - you are not in charge of it."

Comment: Relax. Let her have her play. Don't waste your energy on this. Not just yet.

Comment: Just keep the paperwork, emails etc in detail.

Comment: QA reports to me.  PM recently got reorganized so she reports to the VP

Answer (score 15):

It's pretty obvious the PM doesn't respect your authority. To some extent, that doesn't matter - at least as long as your VP (and anyone else in-between you and your VP) does respect your authority.

If they do, the conversation between the PM and your VP will be pretty short :

> Thanks for telling me this, now go and sort it out with SomeGuy1989. Only bring this back to me if you can't sort it out between you.

If your VP doesn't respect your authority, then you have bigger problems than your PM.